# Apache olingo basic authentication encoding issue

Tags: java, encoding, authorization, olingo

I am developing OData client with Apache olingo, credentials contains native characters and should be read in UTF-8 for Base64 encoding of "Authorization" header. 
The first way to go was standard suggested by Olingo:

```
EdmEnabledODataClient client = ODataClientFactory.getEdmEnabledClient(endpointURI, ContentType.JSON);
client.getConfiguration().setHttpClientFactory(new BasicAuthHttpClientFactory(username, password));
```

But that didn't not work for me, because Olingo reads "username" and "password" bytes in US-ASCII charset for Base64 encoding, and my username turns to ??? . 
On HTTP client level, there is a way to pass charset to **org.apache.http.impl.auth.BasicSchemeFactory** , but I found no way to customize it on Olingo level.

My second attempt was adding a raw header:

```
URI searchURI = client.newURIBuilder(endpointURI)
            .appendEntitySetSegment(segment)
            .top(10)
            .addQueryOption(QueryOption.FORMAT, "json")         
            .build();
    ODataEntitySetRequest<ClientEntitySet> request = client.getRetrieveRequestFactory().getEntitySetRequest(searchURI);
    String auth = Base64.encodeBase64String(String.format("%s:%s", username, password).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            request.addCustomHeader("Authorization", "Basic "+ auth);
    ODataRetrieveResponse<ClientEntitySet> response = request.execute();
```

But it appears that Olingo actually sends 2 HTTP requests under request.execute call . First one is for data, it contains my header, passed authorization and returns data - fine. But then second request is for metadata, without Authorization header, and returns 401 Unauthorized. So the final result is exception. 
I need a way to add basic auth. that will work through full Olingo request cycle (multiple http requests, and use UTF-8 charset for my credentials. Or, disable metadata call somehow (may be not possible, if Olingo always uses it for response object construction)

Answer (score 4):

Found a solution, but still interested in recommended way by Olingo

```
            EdmEnabledODataClient client = ODataClientFactory.getEdmEnabledClient(endpointURI, ContentType.JSON);
            final String auth = Base64.encodeBase64String(String.format("%s:%s", username, password).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            client.getConfiguration().setHttpClientFactory(new DefaultHttpClientFactory() {
                @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                @Override
                public DefaultHttpClient create(HttpMethod method, URI uri) {
                    final DefaultHttpClient client = super.create(method, uri);
                    client.addRequestInterceptor(new HttpRequestInterceptor() {
                       @Override
                       public void process(HttpRequest request, HttpContext context) throws HttpException, IOException {
                           request.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + auth);
                    }
                });
                return client;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Do you have any news on this? I got the same problem :-/ 401 Error with basic auth, Postman request works, normal ODATA Client doesn't, your workaround doesn't work for us.

Comment: No, I don't have any news. The above solution works for us, and now it is in production.

Comment: It worked for me too (even now with Basic Auth). My problem was, that the URI was not encoded in UTF-8 after setting some attributes like '&format=json, the server responded with 401 which made it confusing.

I had to encode the URI at the end and put the result back into the setter. Is there a solution to set the encoding directly to UTF-8?

Anyway, thanks for your time.

Comment: I'd try to use Authenticator class as described here https://www.baeldung.com/java-http-url-connection